# Can't vote to migrate from meta

Tags: support, bug, close-reasons, migration, meta

Another one to pile on the heap:

The new closing system seems to have some inadvertent effects on meta, like a strange typo, and the loss of the option to vote to migrate to main:

[image]

---

[image]

Moreover, as I specified in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10046/43351), the "help center" link will relegate to the help of the main site (which may lead to wrong conclusions about what is on-topic on meta).

Can we please have some meaningful, grammatically correct "off-topic" close reasons?